# laravel query has an underscore sign extra

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

These are my models

```
class DateAttribute extends Eloquent{
public function xmlDocument(){
        return $this->belongsTo('XMLDocument');
    }
}

class XMLDocument extends Eloquent{
public function dateAttribute(){
        return $this->hasOne('DateAttribute');
    }
}
```

the `XMLDocument`  model has one of `DateAttribute` model. I can insert successfully to both tables.

now I am trying to read a specific xml document. in other words, I am trying to view that xml document.

I tried this in my view:

```
 <td>{{$xmlDocument->dateAttribute->name}}</td>

I got this error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'date_attribute.x_ml_document_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `date_attribute` where `date_attribute`.`x_ml_document_id` = 10 limit 1)
```

I don't know why is that happening, I have many many relationships and all are working, just this one doesn't work

please notice that the error message has `x_ml_document_id` there is an `underscore` between the `x` and the `ml`, I searched all the code, I don't have that word at all.

help please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the naming of your models. Eloquent by default tries to find out what local and foreign keys you are using by reading your model names. As you can see, your `DateAttribute` model becomes `date_attribute`. CamelCase gets converted to underscore.

> Take note that Eloquent assumes the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. In this case, Phone model is assumed to use a user_id foreign key. If you wish to override this convention, you may pass a second argument to the hasOne method. Furthermore, you may pass a third argument to the method to specify which local column that should be used for the association

So, to fix your issue, define your foreign/local keys in the second and third parameter of `hasOne`. E.g:

```
class XMLDocument extends Eloquent
{
    // Define table name
    protected $table = 'xml_document';

    public function dateAttribute()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('DateAttribute', 'xml_document_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Plus, I found the solution before and I was comming to type it as an asnwer :) many thanks

Comment: In fact it should be `xml_document_id` there, not `date_attr_id`, unless the latter is a foreign key on the `date_attribute` table, which I suppose is not the case.

Comment: @deczo yes it is `xml_document_id`, that is why I tried and it works